# PlayerPrefs na Unity com variável Booleana?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

O  `PlayerPrefs` Tem algo parecido ou ele mesmo pode usar variável booleana.

exemplo:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt() // e para inteiros
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html), apenas é possível guardar valores do tipo float, int e string.

Como não é possível armazenar booleanos, você pode armazenar 0 ou 1 e converte-los, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public static class CustomPlayerPref
{
    public static bool GetBool (string key)
    {  
        return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key) == 1;
    }

    public static void SetBool (string key, bool state)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt (key, state ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara nativo do Unity não da, mas se você acessar esse link

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=PlayerPrefsx

E copiar o script JS e colar em alguma pasta no projeto, da pra usar com bool sim, igual o playerPrefs, mas ai tu só escreve

playerPrefsX.getBool ou .setBool,

Na época eu achei um que salvava ate Colors, mas nao achei agora pra postar aqui hahaha, espero que ajude !